# Can't write firebase database, getting empty error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Been trying to write to my Firebase Realtime Database with something as simple as this in my react-native app:

```
newTips = () => {
    firebase.database().ref('users/').set({
      tips: "tips"
    }).then((data)=>{
        //success callback
        console.log('data ' , data)
    }).catch((error)=>{
        //error callback
        console.log('error ' , error)
    })
  }
```

But it is not writing and I am getting this yellow message in Expo. Any idea what the issue is? Auth works perfectly however.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There should be a more complete error message than that. Maybe it'll show if you open the triangle in front of `Stacktrace`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Added some more screens.. This is so frustrating

Comment: That last screenshot looks like a stack trace. Do any of the file names correspond to code you wrote? If so, the line number should give you a hint as to where the problem happens. Unfortunately there's still no useful error message, so it's hard to say more.

Comment: None, of these files is files that I made. So must be in the node stack...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by chaning from Firebase Realtime to Firestore. Works perfectly.

```
newTips = () => {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

      if (user) {
        email = user.email;
        // User is signed in.
        console.log('Logged in user: ' + email)
        firestore.collection("tips").add({
            user: user.email,
            tips: "bla bla"
        })
        .then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
      } else {
        // User is signed out.
        console.log('No user signed in')
      }
    })
  }
```